# Установить право unfiltered_html для пользователей определённой роли в WordPress в режиме Multisite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Внезапно выяснилось, что в режиме Multisite привилегия `unfiltered_html` есть только у суперадмина. Мне необходимо вернуть её админам и редакторам.
Следующий код помог решить эту задачу:

```
<php
    $role_object = get_role('administrator');
    $role_object->add_cap('unfiltered_html', true);
    $role_object = get_role('editor');
    $role_object->add_cap('unfiltered_html', true);
?>
```

Но у пользователей с ролью админов и редакторов возможность не появилась.
Получается интересное: у роли возможность установлена, но ни вновь создаваемые пользователи с этой ролью, ни уже существующие привилегией не обладают.

Вот что я получаю, выполняя следующий код:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'editor',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users($args);
    $editor_caps = get_role('editor')->capabilities;
    foreach ($editor_caps as $cap => $val) {
        if ($cap == 'unfiltered_html' && $val) {
            echo '<p>Для роли editor установлена возможность <strong>' . $cap . '</strong></p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <h4>Список всех пользователей с правом editor</h4>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            $user_can = user_can($user_id, 'unfiltered_html');
            ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo esc_html($user->display_name) . '[' . esc_html($user->user_email) . '] - '; ?>
                <?php echo $user_can ? 'право unfiltered_html <span style="color:green;">включено</span>' : 'право unfiltered_html <span style="color:red;">отсутствует</span>'; ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
```

[image: Список пользователей с правом editor]

Два последних пользователя были созданы уже после обновления прав у ролей editor и administrator.
Хотелось бы понимать, по какой причине это происходит и можно ли как-то решить эту задачу в целом для роли, а не для пользователей по отдельности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Магия происходит в map_meta_cap():

```
        case 'unfiltered_html':
            // Disallow unfiltered_html for all users, even admins and super admins.
            if ( defined( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML' ) && DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML ) {
                $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            } elseif ( is_multisite() && ! is_super_admin( $user_id ) ) {
                $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            } else {
                $caps[] = 'unfiltered_html';
            }
            break;
```

Но в конце этой функции есть фильтр

```
    /**
     * Filters a user's capabilities depending on specific context and/or privilege.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @param string[] $caps    Array of the user's capabilities.
     * @param string   $cap     Capability name.
     * @param int      $user_id The user ID.
     * @param array    $args    Adds the context to the cap. Typically the object ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'map_meta_cap', $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args );
```

Думаю, что такого кода будет достаточно для решения проблемы.

```
/**
 * @param string[] $caps    Array of the user's capabilities.
 * @param string   $cap     Capability name.
 * @param int      $user_id The user ID.
 * @param array    $args    Adds the context to the cap. Typically the object ID.
 */
function my_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if (
        'unfiltered_html' === $cap &&
        is_multisite() &&
        ( user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) || user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) )
    ) {
        return [ 'unfiltered_html' ];
    }

    return $caps;
}

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'my_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: идеально! спасибо за помощь